# How to create ScrollViewer CustomControl/UserControl in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am having some trouble for creating a usercontrol for scrollviewer,
I have style the scrollBar according to our design and theme.
I want to incorporate ScrollBar in ScrollViewer, i am notable to create a custom control because ScrollViewer is a sealed class.
please help me, and suggest me if there is another solution for that,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are doing is styling the Scrollbars then you just need to create a style the for the ScrollViewer. Take the default style for it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278065%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).  Then adjust the Scrollbars inside it to use your new Scrollbar style.